# What is Iteration Number in modeling?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics, biology

I am a biologist. Referring to mathematical modeling for biological data in the literature.

Could someone explain what is the "Iteration Number" of modeling and the meaning of the up and down values of a figure similar to below [image]

Does this have to be stabilized over the number of iterations; if the model has to work?

Comment: I think we need more information to answer this. A whole bunch of algorithms are “iterative”, meaning that they compute a sequence of values $x_k$, for $k = 1,2,\ldots$, with each value depending on the previous values or previous values. But there are so many algorithms like this that it’s hard to say anything more specific. The algorithm could be numerically solving a differential equation, for example. In that case, $x_k$ might be an approximation to $x(t_k)$, where $x$ is a function that satisfies a given differential equation and $t_k$ is a particular instance in time.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for your kind reply. This is related to enzymes regulation and signal transduction pathway modeling during growth and development. I am unable to explain morethan as i only have high school mathematics knowledge. I hadn’t had opportunity to study calculus and limits. Although I have survived my career without advanced mathematics— I regret when it comes to understanding complex biological networks, modeling type studies. I wish if I can learn important mathematics concepts for biology again— yet hesitate how to and feeling old.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the image you included?  Without the context this could mean almost anything.